# How to instantly show the likes and dislikes count in the react ui

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

So i am trying to implement like and dislike functionality, whenever someone clicks the like button the like array is updated but the count of the array is shown in the ui if refresh not before that

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as timeago from "timeago.js";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import MoreVertRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVertRounded";
import ThumbUpOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpOutlined";
import ThumbUpAltRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAltRounded";
import ThumbDownOffAltRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownOffAltRounded";
import ThumbDownAltRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownAltRounded";
import CommentRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CommentRounded";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const { user: currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const likePost = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.put(`/post/${post?._id}/like`, { userId: currentUser._id });
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  const dislikePost = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.put(`/post/${post?._id}/dislike`, {
        userId: currentUser._id,
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/users?userId=${post.userId}`);
      setUser(response.data);
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [post.userId]);

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post-top">
        <div className="user">
          <Link
            to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}
            style={{ color: "inherit", textDecoration: "none" }}
          >
            <img
              src={
                user?.profilePicture
                  ? user?.profilePicture
                  : "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/no-user-profile-picture-24185395.jpg"
              }
              alt=""
            />
          </Link>
          <div className="user-info">
            <Link
              to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}
              style={{ color: "inherit", textDecoration: "none" }}
            >
              <span className="username">{user?.username}</span>
            </Link>
            <span>{timeago.format(post.createdAt)}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <MoreVertRoundedIcon style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
        </div>
      </div>
      {post?.image ? <hr /> : <hr style={{ display: "none" }} />}
      <div className="post-center">
        {post?.image ? (
          <img src={post?.image} alt="" />
        ) : (
          <img style={{ display: "none" }} />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="post-desc">
        <div className="description">
          <span>{user?.username}</span>
          <span>{post?.description}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="post-bottom">
        <div className="icons" onClick={likePost}>
          {post?.likes.includes(currentUser?._id) ? <ThumbUpAltRoundedIcon /> : <ThumbUpOutlinedIcon /> }
          <span>{post?.likes.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={dislikePost}>
          {post?.likes.includes(currentUser?._id) ? <ThumbDownAltRoundedIcon /> : <ThumbDownOffAltRoundedIcon />}
          <span>{post?.dislikes.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="icons">
          <CommentRoundedIcon />
          <span>10</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

I tried using use effects but i think i did something wrong in the use effect, and i am only using react context api not redux

Comment: so you get the likes array length from the 'post' object - which is a prop being passed to this component - the reason this only works when you refresh is that you are re-fetching the post and passing it to the component. So, either re-fetch the post after you add a like OR set a state with the post likes and add a setState to add to the counter after you post a like (I don't like the latter so much)

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 solutions:

1- If your **put** endpoint returns the whole post information after liking or disliking a post, you need to create new state to hold your post information as follow and update it accordingly:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as timeago from 'timeago.js';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import MoreVertRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVertRounded';
import ThumbUpOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpOutlined';
import ThumbUpAltRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAltRounded';
import ThumbDownOffAltRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownOffAltRounded';
import ThumbDownAltRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownAltRounded';
import CommentRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CommentRounded';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({}),
    [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState(post);

  const { user: currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const likePost = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.put(`/post/${currentPost?._id}/like`, { userId: currentUser._id });
      setCurrentPost(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  const dislikePost = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.put(`/post/${currentPost?._id}/dislike`, {
        userId: currentUser._id,
      });
      setCurrentPost(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/users?userId=${currentPost.userId}`);
      setUser(response.data);
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [currentPost.userId]);

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post-top">
        <div className="user">
          <Link
            to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}
            style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'none' }}
          >
            <img
              src={
                user?.profilePicture
                  ? user?.profilePicture
                  : 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/no-user-profile-picture-24185395.jpg'
              }
              alt=""
            />
          </Link>
          <div className="user-info">
            <Link
              to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}
              style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'none' }}
            >
              <span className="username">{user?.username}</span>
            </Link>
            <span>{timeago.format(currentPost.createdAt)}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <MoreVertRoundedIcon style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} />
        </div>
      </div>
      {currentPost?.image ? <hr /> : <hr style={{ display: 'none' }} />}
      <div className="post-center">
        {currentPost?.image ? (
          <img src={currentPost?.image} alt="" />
        ) : (
          <img style={{ display: 'none' }} />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="post-desc">
        <div className="description">
          <span>{user?.username}</span>
          <span>{currentPost?.description}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="post-bottom">
        <div className="icons" onClick={likePost}>
          {currentPost?.likes.includes(currentUser?._id) ? (
            <ThumbUpAltRoundedIcon />
          ) : (
            <ThumbUpOutlinedIcon />
          )}
          <span>{currentPost?.likes.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={dislikePost}>
          {currentPost?.likes.includes(currentUser?._id) ? (
            <ThumbDownAltRoundedIcon />
          ) : (
            <ThumbDownOffAltRoundedIcon />
          )}
          <span>{currentPost?.dislikes.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="icons">
          <CommentRoundedIcon />
          <span>10</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

2- If you have an endpoint which fetches the required post information you can update your code as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as timeago from 'timeago.js';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import MoreVertRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVertRounded';
import ThumbUpOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpOutlined';
import ThumbUpAltRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAltRounded';
import ThumbDownOffAltRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownOffAltRounded';
import ThumbDownAltRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownAltRounded';
import CommentRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CommentRounded';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({}),
    [currentPost, setCurrentPost] = useState(post);

  const { user: currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const updatePostData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`/post/${currentPost?._id}`, { userId: currentUser._id });
      setCurrentPost(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const likePost = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.put(`/post/${currentPost?._id}/like`, { userId: currentUser._id });
      await updatePostData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  const dislikePost = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.put(`/post/${currentPost?._id}/dislike`, {
        userId: currentUser._id,
      });
      await updatePostData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/users?userId=${currentPost.userId}`);
      setUser(response.data);
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [currentPost.userId]);

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post-top">
        <div className="user">
          <Link
            to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}
            style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'none' }}
          >
            <img
              src={
                user?.profilePicture
                  ? user?.profilePicture
                  : 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/no-user-profile-picture-24185395.jpg'
              }
              alt=""
            />
          </Link>
          <div className="user-info">
            <Link
              to={`/profile/${user?.username}`}
              style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'none' }}
            >
              <span className="username">{user?.username}</span>
            </Link>
            <span>{timeago.format(currentPost.createdAt)}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <MoreVertRoundedIcon style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} />
        </div>
      </div>
      {currentPost?.image ? <hr /> : <hr style={{ display: 'none' }} />}
      <div className="post-center">
        {currentPost?.image ? (
          <img src={currentPost?.image} alt="" />
        ) : (
          <img style={{ display: 'none' }} />
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="post-desc">
        <div className="description">
          <span>{user?.username}</span>
          <span>{currentPost?.description}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="post-bottom">
        <div className="icons" onClick={likePost}>
          {currentPost?.likes.includes(currentUser?._id) ? (
            <ThumbUpAltRoundedIcon />
          ) : (
            <ThumbUpOutlinedIcon />
          )}
          <span>{currentPost?.likes.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="icons" onClick={dislikePost}>
          {currentPost?.likes.includes(currentUser?._id) ? (
            <ThumbDownAltRoundedIcon />
          ) : (
            <ThumbDownOffAltRoundedIcon />
          )}
          <span>{currentPost?.dislikes.length}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="icons">
          <CommentRoundedIcon />
          <span>10</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```